# Quickly verify two "cells" match, in large data sets

Tags: bash, verify

I'm working with large sets of data (a few hundred lines over each check) and was wondering what the most efficient way of comparing two different sets of data would be.

What I'm looking for would be finding differences like the ones below:

From source 1:

```
site1.49729    site2.80124             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49730    site2.80125             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49734    site2.80126             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49735    site2.80127             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49736    site2.80128             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49737    site2.80129             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49738    site2.80131             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49752    site2.80171             /path/path/path/path
```

From source 2:

```
site1.49729    site2.80124             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49730    site2.80125             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49734    **site2.1234**              /path/path/path/path               
site1.49735    site2.80127             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49736    site2.80128             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49737    **site2.12345**             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49738    site2.80131             /path/path/path/path               
site1.49752    site2.80171             /path/path/path/path
**site1.49735    site2.99999               /path/path/path/path**
```

differences highlighted with **

What would be the most efficient way to ensure that everything in the second column of the two commands is #1 not missing, and #2 matches the records exactly?

Any thoughts on where to start with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just running a `diff` against source 1 and source2.  It will show you lines which contain differences.  Put the contents of source 1 in `s1.txt` and the contents of source 2 in `s2.txt` and run the command:

`$ diff -y s1.txt s2.txt`

This will show you the differences between both of the files.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I'd never used side by side diff before, and it works great for this!

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'diff' command. It generates output that looks like this for your case:

```
< site1.49734    site2.80126             /path/path/path/path
---
> site1.49734    **site2.1234**              /path/path/path/path
6c6
< site1.49737    site2.80129             /path/path/path/path
---
> site1.49737    **site2.12345**             /path/path/path/path
8c8,9
< site1.49752    site2.80171             /path/path/path/path
\ No newline at end of file
---
> site1.49752    site2.80171             /path/path/path/path
> **site1.49735    site2.99999               /path/path/path/path**
```

There are many text editors that provide a GUI for diffing files or viewing a diff (e.g. Notepad++)